# Create new role with specific ACL rights

Tags: magento2, user-roles, acl

I want to create a new admin role with some rights.

So I use the following code :

```
    $role = $this->roleFactory->create();
    $role->setName('MyNewRole')
        ->setPid(0)
        ->setRoleType(RoleGroup::ROLE_TYPE)
        ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN);
    $role->save();

    $resource = [
        'Magento_Sales::sales'
    ];
    $this->rulesFactory->create()
        ->setRoleId($role->getId())
        ->setResources($resource)
        ->saveRel();
```

This code works. However, I would like all the subcategories of Sales, not only "Magento_Sales::sales".

> For that, I know I can put the listing of all subcategories (for
>   example : Magento_Sales::create Magento_Sales::invoice
>   Magento_Sales::reorder ...)

But it's very long: there are 47

Does someone know how to do? Something like "Magento_Sales::*" or a recursive method maybe?

Comment: See how Magento reads acl.xml to built the tree in admin. From there you can deduce the resources you need.

Comment: A know the resource I need (there are 47). Is there a way to make some recursive code instead of list all 47 resources ?

Comment: What is the reason to create it using code? Posible with admin panel.

Comment: I have a lot of roles to create and I want to create them by Setup to have the code on all my environments.